# How to see references in Flow errors?

Tags: visual-studio-code, flowtype

I'm using Flow in VS Code with vscode-flow-ide.

When there is an error, the error message contains reference numbers in square brackets, but doesn't appear to give the locations or definitions of those references.

For instance, here: how can I see what the `[1]` refers to?

[image]

Comment: That's not the official plugin, consider using `flowtype.flow-for-vscode` https://github.com/flowtype/flow-for-vscode instead which would have the references

Comment: I did try that, but it didn't seem to help. This non-official plugin seems to have much better ratings than the official one.